# How to obtain an old linux distribution?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

Is it possible to download load distribution of linux, even the old distributions have kernel 2.6.x.x but I need a distribution with 2.4 kernel.

Is it possible to recompile the 2.4 kernel on a distribution with 2.6 kernel?

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do this?

Comment: @Billy: I have to have a 2.4 kernel to play my copy of *Myth II: Soulblighter* for Linux, of course! What are you, some kind of philistine?

Comment: Actually i needed to do a bufferoverflow demonstration in class...and i volunteered...now i cant back off...i thought i would find the distro on the net...but its been 2 weeks...no luck yet

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to demonstrate a buffer overflow, try using Damn Vulnerable Linux

Answer (score 1):

At distrowatch.com, they have specs on old versions and links to downloads. For example, on the page about [Red Hat](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat) distributions, you can see that RHEL 3.9 was the last to include a 2.4 kernel. Only source RPMs (SRPM) are available for download, but you can follow the ISO link for RH 9 to [download ISO files](ftp://archive.download.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/9/en/iso/i386/).

Comment: Or you could just use one of its derivatives.

Comment: True. In fact you don't even need to use Red Hat. I chose Red Hat as an example to walk through what distrowatch provides.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking on the websites of the big distributions that were around during the 2.4 era. I'd try Debian, RedHat, Slackware, or SUSE.

Here is a link to [the Debian archive](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/). I believe that Woody (3.0) was a 2.4 based distribution, and there are much older versions than that if you really want.

Comment: i tried slackware....but kernel version was 2.6

Comment: @Vinod: You'll have to dig for an *old* version. The leading edge has been 2.6 for years now, so that's a ways back. I *know* Debian keeps pointers to prehistoric versions on their site.

Comment: i will check  ..

Comment: recompiling is it possible with 2.4?

Comment: @dmckee i looked through those archives....how do i download the woody distru??

Comment: @Vinod: dig a little...woody...main...disks-<architecture of choice>... It's not user friendly because they don't want you using ancient versions unless you know what you're doing: you might get a bad impression of them, 'ya know? Hey! Look! They're floppy images! Those load a minimal, over the net install. And there are tftp boot instructions.

Comment: @Vinod: Looks like sarge support 2.4 kernels as well, and that one has cdrom images. Much better, I assure you.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 3 and its derivatives use a 2.4 kernel, but there isn't much life left in them.

Comment: can i recompile the kernel with 2.4??

Comment: You can recompile anything you like any way you like. But don't expect a modern distribution to work with 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC Fedora Core 1 (Yarrow) should fit the bill

http://download.uta.edu/software/linux/fedora/core/1/i386/iso/

Answer (score 0):

OpenWRT still ships 2.4 kernels for the Linksys WRT54g.